# Why are so many settings in Linux limited to 65536. what is the special meaning?

Tags: linux-kernel, limit

There are many limits in the Linux operating system that are set to 65536.
For example:

- The number of TCP ports, up to 65536
- Maximum number of file opens, up to 65536
- MSGMAX parameter is usually set to 65536 (64KB)
- Maximum number of connections to the network 65536 (not sure)

And so on.

1. What other settings are also 65536?
2. What is special about the number 65536?2 to the 16th power?16KB
   (65536bytes)?

Comment: The limit of 65536 is due to the fact that file descriptors are 16-bit integers. This means that the maximum number of file descriptors that can be opened at any given time is 2^16 = 65536. This limit applies to other operating systems, not just Linux. However, this limit does not apply to the number of connections that can be made. The number of connections is limited by system configuration and memory.

Comment: ports: it is a limit of internet. Or a design decision.

Comment: UNIX originally ran on the PDP-11, a 16-bit machine.  Many 2-byte fields in protocols and system code have been just too much trouble to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
What is special about the number 65536?
```

It's special because it's a power of two and in binary this matters :). Other than that there's nothing particularly special about the 2^16 number. The reason it was chosen as the number of port numbers is historical and related to how the standard for TCP was born. The following is an old document giving some details on an initial cut of TCP.

https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos561/papers/cerf74.pdf

Note, a lot of work on protocols had already happened before this by a lot of people. In one of the RFC's it was actually proposed to have port numbers be 24 bits but that got changed.

```
Why are so many settings in Linux limited to 65536
```

The reason you find it every where in linux is because it satisfies the sweet spot of being able to squeeze two of them into a 32 bit integer and it's a conservative number for a lot of limits. If you look through the linux source code a lot of the limits are conservative and not actually that great for production systems. Mature teams running linux have tweaked their linux limits in innumerable ways for their workloads and some of the performance gains you can get can be dramatic which is why you can find a ton of content online talking about tweaking the kernel.

When you see a limit in linux don't assume that it's fixed, almost invariably there's a way to tune it.

```
What other settings are also 65536?
```

Too numerous to mention. If you grep the linux source there are more than 1000 occurrences of the string "65536" and this does not include all the constants and variables using the number peppered throughout the code.

The comment mentioning that file descriptors being 16 bit is wrong. As far as I'm aware file descriptors in linux have always been a 32 bit integer.